# Why is my auto layout constraint not working?

Tags: ios, xcode, ios6

I have the following Table View Controller (which is actually a custom subclass of UITableViewController):

[image]

What I want is for `Make:`'s label to be lined up with `Model:`'s from the front, which I assume is leading. (Basically I want the words to start at the same x pos)

I have the following code to accomplish this:

```
    NSLayoutConstraint *constraint = [NSLayoutConstraint
        constraintWithItem:self.carMakeLabel
        attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeading
        relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
        toItem:self.carModelLabel
        attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeading
        multiplier:1.0
        constant:0];

    [self.view addConstraint:constraint];
```

But when I run it, they stay as they are in the screenshot below. Also, the application crashes after a little while. (Saying something along the lines of Thread 1: EXC_BREAKPOINT

Comment: what is the OS of target device on which you are running the app?

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't need to add a constraint in code, you should be able to do it all in IB. Sometimes it can be difficult to do, but if center the labels in the cell vertically, and give them both the same fixed distances to the superview on the left and right, then they will be aligned.

I'm not really sure that you can do the kind of constraint you're trying to do here across two cells.

Comment: @DougSmith - I don't understand your comment. I said you should do it all in IB, not in code. I've done it that way, and it works fine.

Comment: I'm doing it in IB, and there's no guidelines to make them line up. See for yourself: http://cl.ly/3y2G1N1m131j

Comment: @DougSmith, no, you can't line them up, you do what I said. Set the distance to the left side of the superview. I opened you project, selected the carModelLabel, and chose the size inspector. Click on the gear next to the "Leading Space To: Table View.." constraint, choose "select and edit", and then change the value to 99 (which is what the value for the upper label was).